# Ctrl+C in a cmd shell causes VSCode to exit

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I execute `code.exe` from a cmd and later on press `Ctrl+C` in that cmd this causes Visual Studio Code to exit immediately, even when a different program is running already.

[image: code goes poof]

I found this issue but there is no documented fix: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40617
This happens regardless of how I run code:

- `code`
- `code .`
- `code &`
- `start code.exe`

It seems to happen that the keystroke is sent to code although it is a child process of cmd. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Issue is valid, but I'm unable to generate, am curious to explore it further. Can you please check whether it's fixed in latest version. I'm using vs-code version `1.33.1`, and windows `Version 10.0.17763.404`. I tried in admin mode cmd as well, but seems working fine for me

Comment: @KamalNayan For me it didn't work in 1.29.1 and (the now updated) 1.33.1. Windows is on 10.0.15063 (Enterprise, not yet updated)